# Louvain and modularity values of the same graph differ a lot in igraph vs networkx

Tags: python, networkx, igraph, modularity

I have a graph and I want to estimate the modularity (Q) based on the Louvain split of the graph.

In python I used igraph and to compare, I also estimated Q in Matlab.
Based on igraph, the Q is negative (weird) whereas the Q based on the Matlab estimation is positive.

I would expect differences in the values but not by so far (+ shows modularity, - shows anti-modularity).
Any idea why this happens?

My code and data (https://gofile.io/?c=h24mcU):

**PYTHON**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from igraph import *

A = scipy.io.loadmat('A.mat')['A']

graph = Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(A.tolist(), mode=ADJ_UNDIRECTED, attr="weight", loops=False)
Louvain = graph.community_multilevel(weights=graph.es['weight'], return_levels=False)
Q = graph.modularity(Louvain)
print(Q)

-0.001847596203445795
```

**MATLAB (Brain Connectivity Toolbox)**
using community_louvain.m: Louvain community detection algorithm

```
clear all
load('A.mat')
[M,Q]=community_louvain(A);

Q =

   0.1466
```

**PYTHON** version of **community_louvain.m:** https://github.com/aestrivex/bctpy/blob/f9526a693a9af57051762442d8490dcdf2ebf4e3/bct/algorithms/modularity.py#L71,

```
import bct

split, Q = bct.community_louvain(A)
Q
0.14659657544165258
```

again I get approx. 0.1466 that matches the Matlab and Python BCT-based results but is far from the `igraph` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found.

I expected igraph to understand this since I defined a weighted adjacency matrix but I need to **explicitly** pass the `weights` argument in `modularity()`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from igraph import *

A = scipy.io.loadmat("A.mat")['A']
np.fill_diagonal(A,0.0)

# igraph
graph = Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(A.tolist(), mode=ADJ_UNDIRECTED, attr="weight", loops=False)
Louvain = graph.community_multilevel(weights=graph.es['weight'], return_levels=False)
Q = graph.modularity(Louvain, weights=graph.es['weight'])
print(Q)

#bctpy
com, q = bct.community_louvain(A)
print(q)

0.14133150351832535

0.14133150351832674
```